# Take account screen size to display Django website

Tags: css, django

I'm a bit lost with `CSS` handling in order to manage stylesheet about `screen size`. I'm developing a `Django` website project and I'm confronting to a very delicate situation.

My project is developped on a very good screen (Retina screen) with a very high resolution. But, when I'm watching my project on a very bad screen resolution, some elements are not situated where it should be.

I put for example part from a .css file corresponding to HTML base template :

```
/* ############################################# */
/* CSS File about Home application properties */
/* ############################################# */

@import url("http://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css");

 /* If screen less than 1440px */
    @media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
    .navbar-right {
        /*padding-left: 250px;*/
        position:absolute; 
        right:2%;
    }
}
     /* If screen bigger than 1440px */
    @media screen and (min-width: 1450px) {
    .navbar-right {
        /*padding-left: 400px;*/
        position:absolute; 
        right:2%;
    }
}

/* Define background color from upper navbar */
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #007A5E !important;
    }

/* DatasystemsEC tab */
.navbar-inverse .container-fluid .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color : white;
    }

/* Tab properties from navbar */
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    color:  white;
    }

footer {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 35%;
}
```

How I can handle CSS stylesheet in order to adapt the file to screens resolution ?

Can you tell me what is right or wrong in following ideas :

- I have to write only % and not px in order to take account screen resolution
- I have to write CSS file firstly for screen resolution between **a** and **b**, then between **b** and **c**, ...

For example, the main content in my Django website corresponding to the `class = "col-sm-8"`. I added `margin-top = -68%` in order to situate the content exactly where I want. But with my friend's screen, the same block is not where it should be.

I'm really new with CSS (and Django too) because I'm learning at the same time I'm coding in order to realize my project.

Thank you if you could help me on this subject.

Answer (score 4):

Current consensus is to approach web development "mobile first". That means start from the smallest screen size and work up to the largest. Bootstrap does exactly that.

In order to decide what are the best suited `media` queries for your project see [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) on MDN. Since you are using Bootstrap, I would suggest following the same [breakpoins](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) to avoid inconsistencies.

Also, consider using `vw` and `vh` instead of percents, when appropriate (I believe this might be part of that `margin-top` problem). Percents are relative to a container's dimensions. `vw` and `vh` are relative to the width and height of the viewport ([see in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)).

Comment: It's a very usefull answer ! I didn't know all this things and I really appeciated your help and advices !